# Scala pattern match with type parameter of type class

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, pattern-matching, implicit-conversion, typeclass

```
sealed trait FormField
case class StringField(name: String, value: String) extends FormField
case class ChoiceField[T : Writes](name: String, value: T, choices: List[T]) extends FormField
```

and then, somewhere else I need to do this:

```
def makeJson(fields: List[FormField]) = fields.map {
   case StringField(name, value) => Json.obj(name -> value)
   case ChoiceField(name, value, _) => Json.obj(name -> value)
}
```

In that last function, scalac/sbt doesn't "understand" that `value` is convertable to json (through its implicit / type class `Writes[T]`). How can I write it so that it "gets it"?

(Note: `Writes[T]` is from Play Framework - it basically says that there is an implicit conversion avaiable for the type `T => JsValue`)

Comment: "No Json serializer found for type Any. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type."

Comment: Can you not create a `Writer[FormField]` instance which can turn a `StringField` or a `ChoiceField` into json ?

Comment: If I tried to create a `Writes[FormField]`, I would still need to pattern match, and I would have the exact same problem.  (EDIT: `makeJson` here _is_ basically a  `Writes[FormField]`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the `Writes` implicit is not in scope when you do pattern matching; the easiest solution would be to keep an explicit reference to it so that you can use it when needed. That way your class definition becomes something like:

```
case class ChoiceField[T](name: String, value: T, choices: List[T])(implicit val writes: Writes[T]) extends FormField
```

And your pattern match:

```
case cf @ ChoiceField(name, value, _) =>
  implicit val tWrites = cf.writes
  Json.obj(name -> value)
```

Comment: Hmm. Am I breaking the conventional "rules" of case classes here btw? Now the case class has two parameter lists, and the writes is not at all meant to be "pattern matched on". Is this nasty code..? What else can I do?

Comment: I don't think that there is any breaking of the rules here: the context bound defined as `[T: Writes]` is just syntactic sugar for the implicit parameter; if you wanted you could've written it as `case class ChoiceField[T: Writes](name: String, value: T, choices: List[T]) { lazy val writes = implicitly[Writes[T]] }` but in the end it's the same thing. To be honest probably I don't know enough about play-json to come up with something more clever than this.

Comment: When pattern matching on a case class, only the first parameter list is taken into account. The other parameter lists (if any) are no different than in a standard class: they are just normal parameters to the the class's primary  constructor.